# R Extract time from timestamp then save as a new column

Tags: r

Please can someone advise where i am going wrong. I have the code below to extract hour, minutes, and seconds. It doesn't work. I am getting an error message:

> Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_'
>   applied to an object of class "function"

```
lubridate::ymd_hms(as.character(d1$timestamp, tz = "UTC"))

df %>% mutate(hours=hour(strptime(d1$timestamp, %H:%M')) %>% 
as.character() )
```

Comment: can you please show an example of the actual data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
# some fake data
df <- data.frame(a = 1, timestamp = '2018-11-11 12:13:14')

# convert as data
library(lubridate)
df$timestamp <- ymd_hms(as.character(df$timestamp, tz = "UTC"))

# add the hour:minutes column
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(hour_ = format(df$timestamp,'%H:%M'))
  a           timestamp hour_
1 1 2018-11-11 12:13:14 12:13
```

Or in only one `dplyr` chain:

```
df %>%
 mutate(hour_ = format(ymd_hms(as.character(df$timestamp, tz = "UTC")),'%H:%M'))
```

Comment: @user5576922 you are welcome, if you share the data that creates the problem, posting a part of them editing the question, it's going to be easier to help.

Comment: How do i define a data frame instead of a specific date, please?

Comment: d1 conatins my data as a data frame

Comment: Could you share the output of `dput(head(d1,5))` editing the question? This line is going to print something like `structure(....`  . They are the first 5 rows of your dataset. Post them editing the question, it's going to be easier and faster to help you having it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I am sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

I would check (try this [function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Xmisc/versions/0.2.1/topics/is.package.loaded)) if the package using that function is actually loaded - and in the right order. 
If you're calling `mutate` from dplyr try `dplyr::mutate` instead of just `mutate`. If that works than it may just be that you have to check if a similar named function from another package is loaded after dplyr and change the order in which you load them if that is a suitable option.